# Remove added class after jQuery appends it onload

Tags: jquery, css, onload

The following jQuery code appends the CSS class `.load` to `.spinner-wrapper` on page load. This accomplishes half of what I'd like.

After 2 seconds, I'd like for jQuery to remove the appended class from `.spinner-wrapper`. The code should be as clean and concise as possible.

**Current Code which adds class onload**

```
$(function() {
  $('.spinner-wrapper').addClass('load');
});
```

Answer (score 6):

If it's simply a time delay you would like to add you can try something like below.

```
$(function() {
  $('.spinner-wrapper').addClass('load');
  setTimeout(function(){
     $('.spinner-wrapper').removeClass('load');
  },2000);
});
```

Answer (score 4):

If you are using JQuery animation:

```
$('.spinner-wrapper').delay(2000).removeClass('load');
```

Else:

```
setTimeout(function(){
      $('.spinner-wrapper').removeClass('load');
},2000);
```

Answer (score 1):

You can't use `delay()` as that only works on the effects queue, and `removeClass()` is not part of that.  See this jsfiddle of two examples...

http://jsfiddle.net/5b5Gm/

You need to use `setTimeout()` like this...

```
$(function() {
    $('.spinner-wrapper').addClass('load');
    setTimeout(function() {
        $('.spinner-wrapper').removeClass('load');
    }, 2000);
});
```